# Find the number of quadruples such that they add up to a specific sum

Tags: algorithm

An array of positive integers is given and you are to find the number of quadruples (i,j,k,l) with i < j < k < l such that they add up to T, where T is given. T < 1+10^6 and N < 5001

The problem seems to be commonly called Four Sum or 4Sum.

The issue is with the following code looping through the array from ayush_ar0204's solution on CodeChef (s is the array):

```cpp
    sort(s,s+n);

    for (long long k=2;k<(n-1);++k){
        if (s[k] >= t)
            break;  

        long long j=k-1;
        for(long long i=0;i<j;++i){
            if(s[i]+s[j]<t){
                ++counts[s[i]+s[j]];
            }
            else{
                i=j;
            }
        }
        for(long long l=k+1;l<n;++l){
            if ((t-(s[k]+s[l]))>=0){
                answer+=counts[t-(s[k]+s[l])];
            }
            else{
                l=n;
            }
        }
    }
```

Check line 21. It says j=k-1. Now, we are operating the loop for i,k,l. Isn't it that we are only checking for the quadruples (i,k-1,k,l) instead of (i,j,k,l)? The code runs fine however, just looks logically incorrect to me.

Comment: You are assuming that the variables `j` and `k` in that solution have the same meaning as the `j` and `k` in the problem description. If the code doesn't make sense given that assumption, then the assumption is probably wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  most notably, you are asking about code on a remote, volatile site.  This is not acceptable -- your question here must be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution reduces the running time from a naive O(n<sup>4</sup>) to O(n<sup>2</sup>). It looks somewhat odd because it's reusing previously calculated information.

At any time, we want `counts[m]` (with `counts` acting as a dictionary) to contain the number of pairs `(i, j)` with `i < j < k` such that `s[i] + s[j] == m`. This is trivially true before the loop starts at `k == 1`, because there are no pairs `(i, j)` so every count is 0. Every time `k` is increased, the only pairs we have to add to the count are ones with `j == k - 1`. If `j < k - 1`, the pair was already counted in the last iteration of the loop. Using the `counts` array means we aren't looking at specific quadruples `(i, j, k, l)` anymore; rather, for each value of `k` we iterate through all possible `l` values and add to the total the stored count of valid `(i, j)` tuples with the correct sum.